# How to make facetime volume off and normally watch video in Macbook?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, facetime

I have a question about using my Mac.
When I'm connected with others in FaceTime and I turn the FaceTime volume off, then I play a video, the volume is also off.

I want the FaceTime volume off but video volume on.
Have any idea how to separate them with the volume control?

Answer (score 2):

Individual Application sound control is only really possible using a 3rd party solution, such as Rogue Amoeba's [SoundSource](https://rogueamoeba.com/soundsource/) ($35)

[image]

There's also their more comprehensive, but at double the price, [Audio Hijack](https://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/), but I think that would be overkill.